# loading images from an array of names into a series of imageviews at runtime

Tags: arrays, xcode, image, imageview

I have `UIImageViews` `image1`, `image2`, `image3` etc.
I have the filenames for the images to go in them in an array called `imageFiles`. (The images change during the program, so I can't preload them.)

Can I use a loop to load the image filenames into the series of images? (I know the code for setting an image into a specific imageView, but can I create an array of `UIImageViews` and load the filename at index 1 of the imageFiles array into image1, the file at index 2 into image2, and so on?

I'm new to Objective C, learning from books, websites, and tutorials as fast as I can.

**Edit:** I found a partial solution and added it as an answer, but  I need to access the array from other methods, like `touchMove`. [I asked this in a subsequent question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958128/declaring-an-array-of-uiimageviews-globally-in-xcode).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Rob! I tried to clean up your question and answer a bit. Keep in mind that you should ask one question per, well, question. (I removed your second question from the answer and added a link to your second question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an answer to my own question, for anyone who is also looking for the same thing (but the solution leads to another problem!)

```
UIImageView *arrayOfImages[10];

int i;

for (i=0; i<10; i++){

  arrayOfImages[i]=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIIMage imageNamed:@"xx.png"]] autorelease];

  arrayOfImages[i].frame = CGRectMake(20,20,80,80);

  arrayOfImages[i].center = CGPointMake(100*(i+1),100);   // puts them across a horizontal row

  [self.view addSubview:arrayOfImages[i]];

}
```

(To get the images from another array, replace the image name with `[filenameArray objectAtIndex[i]]` )

But this method defined the `arrayOfImages` locally, and I need to access the array from other methods, like `touchMove`.

Comment: You can accept this answer using the green question mark (after a delay) if this answered your original question.