# Declaring an array of UIImageViews globally in Xcode

Tags: arrays, xcode, uiimageview

I created an array of ImageViews in a Buttonclicked method:

```
UIImageView *arrayOfImageViews[10]
```

I successfully loaded them on the screen using a loop. (Big accomplishment for this beginner!)

But I want to refer to them in other methods (e.g. `touchMove`).

Where do I declare `arrayOfImageViews` to be both an array and a class of `UIImageView` so that I can use them in other methods? From what I can find, I'm to declare them in the `.h` and above Implementation in the `.m`.  But I can't figure out the code and location to define the object as an array of UIImageViews in anything but the original function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a property.  So in the `.h` file, you want to define the property something like this:

---

```
@interface MyClass: UIView {
    NSArray *arrayOfImageViews;
} 

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *arrayOfImageViews;
```

---

Now in the implementation (`.m` file) You need to bind this property like this

```
@implementation MyClass 

@synthesize arrayOfImageViews;

//now you need to initialize the array of images like this (look for the method viewDidLoad or //just add it)

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSMutableArray *tmpImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    //initialize images here
    [self setArrayOfImageViews:tmpImages];
    [tmpImages release];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

That should do it... Sorry I didn't have time to post code that actually compiles but it should help.  Basically now you have a property on the class and you can access it like `self.arrayOfImages`, or even just `arrayOfImages` (from within `MyClass`).  Also, I used `NSArray` which I suggest you do too.  However you can also use `UIImageView* arrayOfImages` if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks Simeon for the answer. When I attempted to initialize the images, I used tmpImages[1] = [[[UIImageView Alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue.png"]] autorelease]; and set tmpImages.frame... but theses got errors of incompatible types and NSMutableArray having no member named frame. This initiallization works if I first do UIImageView *tmpImages[10], but that puts me back into the problem of defining the array of imageViews locally. (note: not an array of image NAMES). I know I'm missing something about defining things right.